# Form binding with custom mapping to object - how?

Tags: forms, scala, binding, playframework

I have these case class

```
case class Blog(id:Long, author:User, other stuff...)
case class Comment(id:Long, blog:Blog, comment:String)
```

and a form on the client side that submits the data

```
blog_id:"5"
comment:"wasssup"
```

I'm writing some simple code to let a user add a comment to a blog.
The user is logged in so the his `user_id` is not needed from the client side, we know who he is...

I would like to bind the `blog_id` to a `Blog` object loaded from db, and if it doesn't exist show an error.
The examples on play framework docs are not helpful.
They only show mappings for forms that represent a single Object and all of its fields.
Here I'm representing a tuple of a `(b:Blog, comment:String)` and for the `Blog` I'm only supplying it's `id`.

I'd like to have a mapping that would provide me with the **conversion + validation + error messages**, so i can write something like:

```
val form = Form(
    tuple(
      "blog_id" -> blogMapping,
      "comment" -> nonEmptyText
    )
  )
  form.bindFromRequest().fold(...
  formWithErrors => {...
  }, {
    case (blog, comment) => {do some db stuff to create the comment}
  ...
```

The "blogMapping" wlil work like other mappings, it will bind the posted data to an object, in our case a blog loaded from db, and in case it's not successful it will provide an error that we can use on the `formWithErrors =>` clause.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this, the docs are kinda lacking here...
any help is appreciated!

Comment: I accepted James answer, but used something a little different, I will add my answer so others can review it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, this doesn't really look like a binding problem.

The issue is around the Model-View-Controller split. Binding is a Controller activity, and it's about binding web data (from your View) to your data model (for use by the Model). Querying the data, on the other hand, would very much be handled by the Model.

So, the standard way to do this would be something like the following:

```
// Defined in the model somewhere
def lookupBlog(id: Long): Option[Blog] = ???

// Defined in your controllers
val boundForm = form.bindFromRequest()
val blogOption = boundForm.value.flatMap {
  case (id, comment) => lookupBlog(id)
}

blogOption match {
  case Some(blog) => ??? // If the blog is found
  case None => ??? // If the blog is not found
}
```

However, if you are determined to handle database lookup in your binding (I'd strongly advise against this, as it will lead to spaghetti code in the long run), try something like the following:

```
class BlogMapping(val key: String = "") extends Mapping[Blog] {
  val constraints = Nil
  val mappings = Seq(this)

  def bind(data: Map[String, String]) = {
    val blogOpt = for {blog <- data.get(key)
                       blog_id = blog.toLong
                       blog <- lookupBlog(blog_id)} yield blog
    blogOpt match {
      case Some(blog) => Right(blog)
      case None => Left(Seq(FormError(key, "Blog not found")))
    }
  }

  def unbind(blog: Blog) = (Map(key -> blog.id.toString), Nil)

  def withPrefix(prefix: String) = {
    new BlogMapping(prefix + key)
  }

  def verifying(constraints: Constraint[Blog]*) = {
    WrappedMapping[Blog, Blog](this, x => x, x => x, constraints)
  }

}

val blogMapping = new BlogMapping()
val newform = Form(
  tuple(
    "blog_id" -> blogMapping,
    "comment" -> nonEmptyText
  )
)

// Example usage
val newBoundForm = newform.bindFromRequest()
val newBoundBlog = newBoundForm.get
```

The main thing we've done is to create a custom Mapping subclass. This can be a good idea under some circumstances, but I'd still recommend the first approach.

Comment: In the first approach, how do you idiomatically handle form errors?

Comment: If there's some validation in the form (so it could be invalid), then you're probably best off handling form validation separately. So rather than using `boundForm.value.flatMap`, use something like `boundform.fold`, and lookup the blog in the success branch.

Comment: Then it'll be still a deeply-nested spaghetti nightmare ):

Comment: If it gets too deeply nested, then you can refactor blocks into methods. I'd disagree that it makes it spaghetti-ish though. The whole point is to ensure that roles are cleanly separated - form validation doesn't belong in the model, and database lookup doesn't belong in the controller.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up looking at how playframwork's current bindings look like and implementing something similar, but for Blog:

```
implicit def blogFromLongFormat: Formatter[Blog] = new Formatter[Blog] {

override val format = Some(("Blog does not exist", Nil))

def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]) = {
  scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch[Long] either {
    data.get(key).map(s => {
      val blog_id = s.toLong
      val blog = Daos.blogDao.retrieve(blog_id)
      blog.map(Right(_)).getOrElse(Left(Seq(FormError(key, "Blog not found", Nil))))
    }).get
  } match {
    case Right(e:Either[Seq[FormError],Blog]) => e
    case Left(exception) => Left(Seq(FormError(key, "Invalid Blog Id", Nil)))
    case _ => Left(Seq(FormError(key, "Error in form submission", Nil)))

  }
}

def unbind(key: String, value: Blog) = Map(key -> value.id.toString)
}

val blogFromLongMapping: Mapping[Blog] = Forms.of[Blog]
```

Comment: +1 thanks for reminding me I already had custom Binders for JodaTime in my code base, totally forgot they were there ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all in the form definition.

I have made some simple scala classes and objects from your example.

`models/Blog.scala`

```scala
package models

/**
 * @author maba, 2013-04-10
 */
case class User(id:Long)
case class Blog(id:Long, author:User)
case class Comment(id:Long, blog:Blog, comment:String)

object Blog {
  def findById(id: Long): Option[Blog] = {
    Some(Blog(id, User(1L)))
  }
}

object Comment {

  def create(comment: Comment) {
    // Save to DB
  }
}
```

`controllers/Comments.scala`

```scala
package controllers

import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import play.api.data.Form
import play.api.data.Forms._
import models.{Comment, Blog}

/**
 * @author maba, 2013-04-10
 */
object Comments extends Controller {

  val form = Form(
    mapping(
      "comment" -> nonEmptyText,
      "blog" -> mapping(
        "id" -> longNumber
      )(
        (blogId) => {
          Blog.findById(blogId)
        }
      )(
        (blog: Option[Blog]) => Option(blog.get.id)
      ).verifying("The blog does not exist.", blog => blog.isDefined)
    )(
      (comment, blog) => {
        // blog.get is always possible since it has already been validated
        Comment(1L, blog.get, comment)
      }
    )(
      (comment: Comment) => Option(comment.comment, Some(comment.blog))
    )
  )

  def index = Action { implicit request =>
    form.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest,
      comment => {
        Comment.create(comment)
        Ok
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the KISS solution, but I don't like it because it makes 2 trips to the db. one on verification and then another for loading. If the verification succeeds I already want to have the Blog obj, why bother looking it up again? even if it's super fast because of indexing, or orm can load it from cache. Also I use this binding in many other places as well so having to write the same checkIfExistsThenLoad chunk of code is annoying.

Comment: @samz I see your point. I have updated my suggestion so that the Blog is read once from the DB and if not found then a message will be given, otherwise the blog object is used in the comments.

Comment: looks better :-) it definitely works, but if you want to reuse this mapping its a pain writing all of this again. see James Mapping solution or my Formatter --> Mapping solution for reusability :)